# How to get all the checkbox names which are checked from a table?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get all the names of check boxes inside a array , which are all checked

I have tried it this way

(Initially select some check boxes )

```
var tag_names = [];

 $('#tagstablepac').find('label:has(input[type="checkbox"]:checked)').each(function()
         {
                 tag_names.push($(this).data("tagname"));
         });

 console.log(tag_names);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/EUm7v/399/

Comment: on what instance?on checkbox change?or on load?

Comment: should be ok check this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/EUm7v/401/). i just used `$('#tagstablepac').find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function()`

Comment: thanks a lot , its working great .

Comment: glad to help mate :) happy coding

Answer (score 0):

i hope understand your mean if your checkbox like below

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chk"  checked  /> 
<input type="checkbox" name="chk1"  checked  /> 
<input type="checkbox" name="chk2"  checked  /> 
<input type="checkbox" name="chk3"  checked  /> 
<input type="checkbox" name="chk4" /> 
<input type="checkbox" name="chk5"  checked  /> 
<input type="checkbox" name="chk6" />
```

if you want checked check box name in array you can do this

```
$(function(){
   var chkNames=[];
   $("input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function(){
       chkNames.push($(this).attr("name"));
   });
});
```